Allied Telesis AT-9424T/SP stuck in bootloop
I’m facing a boot loop issue with my Allied Telesis AT-9424T/SP switch. After powering it on, the system initializes and attempts to decompress the application image, but it eventually throws an exception and restarts. I suspect the issue might be due to an incompatibility between the bootloader and the application firmware versions. Here’s what I’ve tried and observed so far:
1.  Console Output During Boot:
Boot Loader (ROM) information:
Product Name:      ATS63_LOADER
Product Version:   v3.2.1
Build Date:        Jul  1 2009
Build Time:        11:31:24
System information:
SDRAM:             32MB
CPU speed:         200MHz
Decompressing the Application Image, please wait................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
Decompressed 3255604 bytes from Flash to 11404256 bytes into RAM
Jump to 0x00000100 to start application
2.  Exception Message:

Initializing LoopGuard ....
FATAL - Exception
Bootloader: ATS63_LOADER v3.2.1 Cycle_A    Jul  1 2009 11:31:24
Application: ATS63 v2.11.6J Cycle_C    Jul 22 2013 11:34:29
Module: Init    15:48:29 on 20-Nov-2024
GPR0  = 00004e78   GPR1  = 00d16194   GPR2  = 00ada780   GPR3  = a54b962d
...
Exception Vector: 00001100/Address error at 0062dbe8
I’ve Attempted So Far:
•   Tried accessing the bootloader by pressing Ctrl + B, Ctrl + C, and Esc during boot.
•   Adjusted serial connection parameters to 460800 bps (default) and even 9600 bps for troubleshooting.
•   Identified that the versions of the bootloader (2009) and firmware application (2013) differ, which may be causing the issue.
•   Tried using the reset button (SW1) on the board but didn’t notice any change.
My Questions:
1.  Is the difference between the bootloader and firmware versions likely the cause of this issue?
2.  How can I force the switch into ROM Monitor mode if no keys seem to interrupt the boot process?
3.  Can the SW1 button be used for resetting the device or forcing it into a recovery mode? If yes, how?
4.  Is it possible to update the bootloader via XMODEM or another method without accessing the application firmware?
I appreciate any insights or guidance from those who’ve encountered similar issues. Thank you!
UPD: Some photos of motherboard. Maybe short circiut some contacts will force enter in boot mode?


Have you checked the release notes/readme for the installed firmware version? Did the problem come up after an update? Out of thin air?

I have updated firmware.
But seems that I choose the wrong one.
Flashed firmware for AT-9424T, but my switch is AT-9424T/SP.

Hmm. I think you need to interrupt the boot process before the Decompressing the Application Image. Be sure the correct baud rate is configured - a good indicator is that you can see valid text on the console without having hit any key. A common default is 9600 Bd - the boot loader might have a different default than the later console and it likely cannot be changed as early as required. With the correct baud rate configured, try hitting repeatedly Enter, Space, or Esc right after powering up. Watch closely to see if the output changes.

I try this.
But before flashing new firmware, i choose in bootloader 460800 speed. For loading image with XMODEM. Now i could see some system information on 460800 speed, but after decompressing image process finished i could see system check on 9600 speed.
Then, after LoopGuard init fatal error, switch do all these thing again. I stuck in a bootloop. Pressing any key during switch startup don’t do anything. I simply can’t interrupt startup and access boot menu to flash another image

You're not very likely to find an expert on that vendor/series here, I'm afraid. If the general cues don't help I'd contact vendor support or replace the unit.
